# How to render a loading component with the useEffect hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a loading bar component which I can just import using this:

```
import { CircleToBlockLoading } from "react-loadingg";
```

and I am trying to use it like this which I am sure is incorrect as it renders nothing

```
useEffect(() => {
const timer = setTimeout(() => {
  return(
  <CircleToBlockLoading />
  )
}, 1000);
return () => clearTimeout(timer);
```

}, []);

Below are the links and documentation links for this external loading bar library:

[This is the page for the live demos of several of these loading progress bar components](http://139.196.82.33:8080/iframe.html?id=demo--demo)

[GitHub for these loading component bars](https://github.com/Summer-andy/react-loading)

The loading bar library just lets you import the loading bar and use it as a component like:

```
<LoadingBar />
```

Essentially I am trying to load and show the progress loading bar as the page loads using useEffect hook and then I am trying for it to be hidden and render the rest of the page data. Below is my code at App level where I am trying to achieve this as at App level I render the navbar and the home page etc.

```
import "./App.css";
import React from "react";
import NavRouter from "./components/NavRouter";
import { CircleToBlockLoading } from "react-loadingg";
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";


const App = () => {
const ref = useRef(null);
useEffect(() => {
const timer = setTimeout(() => {
  return(
  <CircleToBlockLoading />
  )
 }, 1000);
 return () => clearTimeout(timer);
 }, []);

return (
 <>
   {/* <CircleToBlockLoading /> */}
   <LoadingBar color="#0edaaf" ref={ref} />
   <NavRouter />
 </>
 );
};
// adding comment
 export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set a local state for tracking the loading. Based on that show the loader or content.

```
import "./styles.css";

// import "./App.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
// import NavRouter from "./components/NavRouter";
import { CircleToBlockLoading } from "react-loadingg";
import { useRef, useEffect } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      // return(
      // <CircleToBlockLoading />
      // )
      setLoading(false);
    }, 5000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {(!loading && <div>MY CONTENT</div>) || (
        <CircleToBlockLoading color="#0edaaf" ref={ref} />
      )}
    </>
  );
};
// adding comment
export default App;
```

Let me know in case you have any doubts.

codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-thunder-u2zj2?file=/src/App.js:0-730

Comment: however this doesn't load in the mobile version?